# Socket: Send request with '\n' and without '\n'?

Tags: perl, sockets, buffer

I'm using IO::Socket::INET for client program (TCP Socket) to communicate with 
(Infosys) Server.

> my $SOCK = new IO::Socket::INET (  PeerAddr => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' , 
>                 PeerPort => '5000',
>                 Proto => 'tcp',
>                 );

```
$Sent_Message = $MAIN::REQUEST_NO . $Bitmap .$main::Req_String ; 
$Total_Len = sprintf("%04d",length( $Sent_Message ) ) ; 

#my $FinalMessage = $Total_Len . $Sent_Message."\n" ; 
my $FinalMessage = $Total_Len . $Sent_Message ; 

print $SOCK $FinalMessage;
```

I'm sending request with "\n"  at end of the line. I didn't receive the response. 
In server side, log says response is sent to the client.

Using wireshark and tcpdump I'm checking the packets, my system is not received any
packets.

I sent the request without '\n', I received the response (immediately) successfully .

Then I sent 3 more request, first one is with '\n' second and third is without '\n'.

All 3 request are waiting for response from server. I have killed the process 1 witch is
sent the request with '\n'. After that other 2 process are received the response.

Same Client Code is sending the request to my local server without '\n'.

The request is not received the server. (Buffer is not flushed).

My doubt is what is the difference between sending the request with '\n' and with out
'\n' ?

Why other 2 process not received the response immediately. (which is sent the request
without '\n') ?

I found the problem is request sending with '\n' at end of the line.

Problem is in server side or client side?

Comment: can you show the part where you send the message? also, what is your platform?

Comment: $Sent_Message = $MAIN::REQUEST_NO . $Bitmap .$main::Req_String ;
$Total_Len    =  sprintf("%04d",length( $Sent_Message  ) ) ;
#my $FinalMessage = $Total_Len . $Sent_Message."\n" ;
 my $FinalMessage = $Total_Len . $Sent_Message ; print $SOCK $FinalMessage;

Comment: I'm using Perl, Operating system is Debian 6.0.6

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible causes.

1. You should be sending a 32-bit integer for the length, but you are sending a four-digit decimal string.
2. You have a bugger *receiver*, one that reads until a newline is received. That's completely inappropriate here since it might end to early or wait too long (if not forever).

It's not a buffering issue; IO::Socket::INET has been disabling buffering on its handles since 1.18 (released in 1997).